# Singularities of Curves in Positive Characteristic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Given a collection of polynomials $\mathscr{F}\subset\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, we can associate to each prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ an affine variety as follows:
$$
(p)\longmapsto Z(\mathscr{F})\subset\mathbb{A}^n_{k}
$$
where $k=\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ (in the case of $p=0$, define $\mathbb{F}_0:=\mathbb{Q}$).  Under this association, which prime ideals $(p)$ correspond to singular varieties?

This question is motivated by exercise I$.5.1$ in Hartshorne.  Part $(c)$ of the exercise asks us to find the singular points of the curve $X$ defined by $x^3=y^2+x^4+y^4$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$.  Having done this exercise I've found that if char $k=0$, then $(0,0)$ is the only singular point of $X$, whereas for characteristics $2$,$7$, and $13$, the curve has other singular points (you can check my result if you'd like; the exercise excludes characteristic $2$, but I've included this case anyway).

Finding the extra singular points and their characteristics involved a fair deal of computing Jacobians and solving simultaneous equations.  Is there another way to find the characteristics which give extra singular points?

I guess this is really a question about the existence of solutions to a system of polynomial equations mod $p$.  In the case of a plane curve, defined by $f(x,y)=0$, we want to know in which characteristics the system of equations
$$
f(x,y)=0
$$
$$
\partial_xf(x,y)=0
$$
$$
\partial_yf(x,y)=0
$$
has a solution.  Given $p$, is there any quick way to tell that this system is consistent?

Comment: It is possible to have an affine variety over $\mathbb{Z}$ which is singular in characteristic $0$ and smooth in finite characteristic. For example, $(x-py-1)x=0$ is two crossing lines in every characteristic but $p$, where the lines become parallel.

Comment: PS: Nice question! I understand in principal what it would take to answer it, but not in practice.

Comment: Thanks for that example David.  I guess I shouldn't assume that my set of primes is finite then.  This means my idea that the desired primes are all factors of some number is a little too naive.

Comment: Now the question is clearer for me. Yet you should probably suppose the scheme $X$ defined by $\mathcal F$ is flat over $\mathbb Z$, otherwise you can just make a disjoint union with anything you want over some $\mathbb F_p$, without any relation with the generic fiber.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, the question is equivalent to finding those primes for which the polynomials $f$, $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ have a common root. More generally, consider three polynomials $f(x,y)$, $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$ with integer coefficients. We can ask for which primes $p$ they have a common root.

It is more common to ask this question for homogenous polynomials $f(x,y,z)$, $g(x,y,z)$ and $h(x,y,z)$, asking when the corresponding equations have a common root in $\mathbb{P}^2$. This is because of the issue I point out in my comment: $x(x-py-1)=0$ is singular for every prime other than $p$, but not for $p$. If you work in projective space, then the set of primes for which there exists a common root will always either be all primes or a finite set. (In this example, the homogenous equation $x(x-py-z)=0$ is singular for all $p$.)

The concept you want here is the **multivariate resultant**: A polynomial in the coefficients of $f(x,y,z)$, $g(x,y,z)$ and $h(x,y,z)$ which vanishes if and only if $f$, $g$ and $h$ have a common root in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

If you compute the multivariate resultant of $f(x,y,z)$, $f_x(x,y,z)$ and $f_y(x,y,z)$, you'll get an integer $R$. The curves $f$, $f_x$ and $f_y$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ will have a common root for the primes which divide $R$. (Because $R=0$ in characteristic $p$ if $p$ divides $R$.) This isn't quite the same as asking when the original polynomial $f(x,y)=0$ is singular, but it is pretty close.

When I started writing this answer, I knew that what you wanted was the multivariate resultant, but I didn't know how to compute it. After digging around online, I think that is because the problem is hard! Here are a few links I fond that might help: [Chapter 4](http://books.google.com/books?id=N9c8bWxkz9gC&lpg=PA46&ots=N8u8tAi-WA&dq=%22multivariate%20resultant%22&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Sturmfels's book Solving Systems of Polynomial Equations, [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90532/any-software-to-compute-multivariable-resultant), [D'Andrea and Dickenstein](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0007036).

Dealing with varieties that aren't hypersurfaces are going to be harder.

Comment: This is awesome.  With the adjustment to considering projective varieties, it is exactly what I had hoped for.  Let me chew on this for a while and see if anyone else has any input before I accept your answer, but thanks a ton!

Comment: You're right.  After looking at your references, it seems like it is very difficult to compute the resultant.  I wonder if things would simplify a bit in the case that the three polynomials are related through differentiation.  Just an initial thought.

Comment: There is a technique called the "Cayley trick" which reduces computations about discriminants (when a hypersurface is singular) to computations about resultants (when multiple hypersurfaces intersect) and vice versa. So, in general, the problems are comparable. However, certainly particular problems may be easier in one way than the other.